# how to parse json result with authentication in php about VendHQ apis

Tags: php, json

How to use get method or post method in php to parse this 
url http://mohamedkaremullasha.vendhq.com/api/products 
user id : xxxxxxxx@gmail.com 
password : xxxxxxx123 Result will be in : json format

sample result over from url from above mentioned

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "e8a29afd-9aba-11e3-a0f5-b8ca3a64f8f4",
      "source_id": "",
      "variant_source_id": "",
      "handle": "tshirt",
      "type": "",
      "variant_parent_id": "",
      "variant_option_one_name": "",
      "variant_option_one_value": "",
      "variant_option_two_name": "",
      "variant_option_two_value": "",
      "variant_option_three_name": "",
      "variant_option_three_value": "",
      "active": true,
      "name": "T-shirt (Demo)",
      "description": "T-shirt, white.  You can delete this once you have some other products setup",
      "image": "http:\/\/mohamedkaremullasha.vendhq.com\/images\/placeholder\/product\/no-image-white-thumb.png",
      "image_large": "http:\/\/mohamedkaremullasha.vendhq.com\/images\/placeholder\/product\/no-image-white-original.png",
      "sku": "tshirt-white",
      "tags": "General",
      "brand_id": "e8a892db-9aba-11e3-a0f5-b8ca3a64f8f4",
      "brand_name": "Generic Brand",
      "supplier_name": "mohamed karemullasha",
      "supplier_code": "",
      "supply_price": "2.00",
      "account_code_purchase": "",
      "account_code_sales": "",
      "inventory": [

      ],
      "price_book_entries": [
        {
          "id": "e8a94a50-9aba-11e3-a0f5-b8ca3a64f8f4",
          "product_id": "e8a29afd-9aba-11e3-a0f5-b8ca3a64f8f4",
          "price_book_id": "e89a21c7-9aba-11e3-a0f5-b8ca3a64f8f4",
          "price_book_name": "General Price Book (All Products)",
          "type": "BASE",
          "outlet_name": "",
          "outlet_id": "",
          "customer_group_name": "All Customers",
          "customer_group_id": "e897507a-9aba-11e3-a0f5-b8ca3a64f8f4",
          "price": 4.95,
          "loyalty_value": null,
          "tax": 0,
          "tax_id": "e89da751-9aba-11e3-a0f5-b8ca3a64f8f4",
          "tax_rate": 0,
          "tax_name": "No Tax",
          "display_retail_price_tax_inclusive": 0,
          "min_units": "",
          "max_units": "",
          "valid_from": "",
          "valid_to": ""
        }
      ],
      "price": 4.95,
      "tax": 0,
      "tax_id": "e89da751-9aba-11e3-a0f5-b8ca3a64f8f4",
      "tax_rate": 0,
      "tax_name": "No Tax",
      "display_retail_price_tax_inclusive": 0,
      "updated_at": "2014-02-21 05:42:10",
      "deleted_at": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

$url = "http://mohamedkaremullasha.vendhq.com/api/products";

$username = 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com';
$password = 'xxxxxxx123';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$out = curl_exec($ch);

print $out;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: can you hint me to get tag base value retrieval on same problem

Comment: You mean to parse the json? you can use json_decode http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php